# ACL extension on main mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, acl

I have the following setup on my servers hgrc file:

```
[extensions]
acl =

[acl]
sources = serve, push

[acl.allow]
```

I was expecting this would block my clients from pushing anything to the repository, however they can still push fine. When I try and push from the server, I get the desired result of not being able to push anything.

Does the ACL extension rely on editing each clients hgrc file?  Doesn't seem like that's very helpful if they can just change their own access.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Thanks for posting this question. I've been using Mercurial for years and I just totally missed the existence of this extension.

Comment: Well let me know if you get yours working! haha.  Also, did you use anything else to accomplish this task by chance?

Comment: Not really. I'm Old School™ and have just been careful about who I let onto my machines. Used in conjunction with [rsnapshots] (http://rsnapshot.org/) (local and remote) of the repositories, I can recover from just about anything that happens to one of my sites. But I definitely like the idea of more fine-grained control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by removing the

```
[acl]
sources= server, push
```

section of my hgrc file. I read that you don't normally need to configure this, so I just removed it and everything seems to be working as desired now!